# How to get the actual JSON from a JsonResult object for a unit test?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, jsonresult

I am wondering how I can take a JsonResult in a unit test and get the stringified JSON to validate it.  I have seen ways to use dynamic types to verify the data, but I need to actually verify the data gets converted to strings appropriately.

Here is my code where I create it:

```
JsonResult result = new JsonResult {Data = new {EncryptedValue = value}};
```

The **value** object I am passing in is actually an type I wrote that can take a value (int, double, DateTime) and when cast to a string, it encrypts the value and I need to ensure that the JsonResult is casting it to a string correctly when stringifying.

Comment: I found the easiest answer by investigating the ExecuteResult method.  I use the JavaScriptSerializer to serialize the JsonResult.Data property.

Answer (score 3):

Just use result.Data

http://www.heartysoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Unit-Testing-JsonResult-Returning-Anonymous-Types

Comment: result.Data has not the json data. Its the anonymous type data. if you want the real serialized json data you must run the ExecuteResult method and mock the controllerContext.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to mock the HttpContext and ControllerContext for that. See the link below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/02/25/unit-testing-the-mvc-jsonresult.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a number of ways, it is very possible.

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2009/02/25/unit-testing-the-mvc-jsonresult.aspx) has a very nice implementation of custom tests written and explained.

In [this post](http://www.heartysoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-Unit-Testing-JsonResult-Returning-Anonymous-Types) the author uses a **custom type** which is being returned and does the same thing.